# Install4j JRE on Mac OS X is placed in .install4j/jre.bundle

Tags: java, macos, install4j

Even though the documentation says:

> The JRE will always be distributed in the directory jre right below
>   the installation root directory

When running my installer on a Mac OS X (Mavericks/Yosemite) which does not have a suitable JRE installed, the bundled JRE is placed in *INSTALLATION_ROOT/.install4j/jre.bundle/* (Contents/Home/jre). This is forcing me to provide special handling when setting up the JRE configuration for my application. Is this a bug in install4 (5.1.15)?

Comment: It behaves _exactly_ as documented, why should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Am I missing something? The documentation says it will always be placed at:
<INSTALLATION_ROOT>/jre
Instead in Mac OS X it's being placed in:
<INSTALLATION_ROOT>/.install4j/jre.bundle

@MarkusWMahlberg is that not a bug?

Comment: It is the way bundles work. Also, I am a bit concerned about configuring a non-standard installation of Java: if the user changes the default Java version (aka install an Oracle JRE/JDK), your configuration may not be used any more. To circumvent that, things like breaking the JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTS mechanisms have to be done - which is a bad idea. Iirc, Install4j offers the possibility to install a global JRE, if none is detected. That's the far better approach, imho.

Comment: Well that's not how Install4j documents bundles work. According to their documentation the JRE will always be placed in a 'jre' directory directly bellow the root installation path. In Mac OS X that's not the case, which is why it's either a bug or a documentation gap. To your point about a 'global JRE', the 'Install as a shared JRE' option is not available in Mac OS X Folder installers.

Comment: Well, maybe that is the problem? It has to be hidden since the installer can not know by any means if the folder the bundle is installed to won't be used for different things and therefor hides its private files as good as possible. But I agree that this behavior should be documented.

Comment: Maybe, but then why is that not the case for Linux and Windows? Anyway, we are in agreement that at least there's a documentation gap there.

Comment: Well, in Linux the FHS basically prevents multi use directories, except for /home. Either a package obeys FHS or it can use /opt, which by definition is the place to put private packages which do not obey FHS. For windows, I can only guess. Maybe because nobody really cares? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the documentation has a gap in this respect. It should say:

---

A statically bundled JRE will always be distributed inside the
installation root directory, on Windows and Linux/Unix
in the directory `jre` and on Mac OS X in `[content directory]/.install4j/jre.bundle`.

The content directory is available from the installer runtime variable `sys.contentDir`.
and resolves to the installation directory for folder media file types and `Contents/Resources/app` for archive media file types.

The actual location of the JRE installation directory is available from
the installer runtime variable `sys.preferredJre` after the "Install files" action
has run.

---

Comment: Thank you @IngoKegel for your answer. Is any of this documented anywhere? The only documentation I could find (quoted in my question) said that the JRE would ALWAYS be placed in the `jre` directory directly under the installation path.

Comment: That part in the documentation will be changed to the above text in install4j 6.0.1. Thanks for your help in finding the outdated information.